# Create Dynamic CSS Class with ReactJS Typescript

Tags: css, reactjs

Hi I'm creating ReactJS component library for personal usage and trying to create a spinner for ex.

I would like to create dynamic css class **(not style attribute of component like style={{}})** according to Spinner's **size**,**transition (for speed)** etc. When I create a style attribute it is displaying on console when view the Inspect in chrome. I would like to create dynamic css for different properties and apply to the component classList.

**Spinner Sizes:**

```
type SizeType = "xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg" | "xl" | "xxl";
```

For example in Chakra UI it is creating css class dynamically and append to the classList of component.

**Chakra UI Spinner**

```
<Spinner thickness='5px' size="lg" speed="3s"  />
```

**Chakra UI Spinner Class => css-do6byp**

```
class="chakra-spinner css-do6byp"
```

How can I do that for different props?

I could not found the solution. I would appreciate it if you cloud help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For example, when you change **speed** prop, chakra ui is creating new css class and append to the classList of component.actually I don't want to use style attribute to hide the css properties from user. I would like to create css class and append to the classList.

Comment: Inline styles aren't hidden from the user. You might tag Chakra.